# Linux Python 2.7 odbc Connection to Progress Open Edge DB

Tags: python, linux, odbc, openedge, progress-db

I can get pyodbc to connect to Progress DB from Windows using a DSN without any problems.

However I need to get it to work from Linux (Centos 6) and although I've downloaded and attempted to install the driver from progress.com, I cannot figure out how to configure the Linux system using the docs from progress.com.  I'm no Linux sysadmin, but not completely lost.

revised 4/22: how do you configure odbc.ini in Centos 6 and will freetds talk to databases other than Sybase and MSSQL that they list in their docs?

I apologize if my initial post was inappropriate, I think my frustration was showing thru.

Thanks,

Fred.

Comment: This post appears to be [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as per *Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.*

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this site](https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/How-to-configure-the-11-6-OpenEdge-64-bit-ODBC-driver-on-Ubuntu-14-04-to-retrieve-data-from-an-OpenEdge-database), I used this documentation to get python3 on a Debian 9 machine connected by ODBC to a remote 10.1c DB. I used the python turbodbc library to manage the connection in python. This should work in python 2.7 as long as it is 64 bit.

Progress Note: This documentation recommends you install "libstdc++5" BEFORE you install the ODBC software. Also make sure that $DLC is set properly.

turbodbc Note: i had to install "libboost-all-dev" and "unixodbc-dev" for turbodbc to install.

good luck